# CPU simulation software

Tags: simulation

Is there any software package that can simulate the inner workings of a processor? The reason I am looking for this is that I am learning about the lower level concepts and I would like a more interactive environment. I am looking for a system which provides a working processor and a way of seeing it work. Additionally it would be nice if it could be modified.

I realise that the question is a bit vague but I have not found software which provides anything resembling what I want and since I work in higher levels I am not familiar with the tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ben Eater](https://eater.net/) has made a video series of building your own [8 bit computer](https://eater.net/8bit), explainaing all the parts. Many people have built that computer, but one guy took it a step further and wrote an emulator and simulator. It's [available online for free](https://cpu.visualrealmsoftware.com/emu/)

The famous 6502 CPU is a lot more complex, but it's available as [Visual 6502](http://www.visual6502.org/JSSim/index.html) as well. I'm not sure if the [65C02 Simulator for Windows](http://sbc.rictor.org/simulator.html) still runs on Windows 10. Maybe you need a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes have you seen [little man computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_man_computer)? It is a simulator for a simple processor, used for education. I think there are a few implementation about.

When you progress to real processors, avoid x86 and x86-64. They are very complex. Good choices to start an are 6502 (old but simple), ARM (modern, and most used processor ≥32bit ).

Answer (score -1):

This guy  has published a series of videos on building a CPU on a breadboard:

[Ben Eater](https://eater.net/) https.//twitter.com/@ben_eater
New video! What's the CPU stack used for and how does it work?

Check it out: https://youtu.be/xBjQVxVxOxc

There is also an iOS App: [CPU8](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/cpu8/id1448776028)